# Is there a way to cancel pending tile requests?

Tags: dictionary, codenameone

I am trying to cancel pending tile requests using the following code on an OSM server:

```
NetworkManager netMgr = NetworkManager.getInstance();
Enumeration connections = netMgr.enumurateQueue();
while (connections.hasMoreElements()) {
    ConnectionRequest connection = (ConnectionRequest)connections.nextElement();
    if (connection.getUrl().indexOf("osm_tiles") > 0) {
        connection.kill();
    }
}
```

I have also tried enumerating with netManager.killAndWait(connection).

I have also tried netMgr.shutdownAsync() with a start() and failed.

In all cases subsequent calls post a request to the network manager fail.

Answer (score 0):

Kill will effectively do that, cause the request to fail and this needs to be handled by the underlying implementation. I'm guessing the `MapComponent` doesn't handle it properly and this propagates onwards which is problematic.

Since we have focused our work on native maps moving forward I'm not sure if this is something fix in the near future. The right thing to do is to follow the error handling logic and handle the case of cancellation properly within the `MapComponent`. If you are able to do this in Codename One you can [submit a pull request](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html).

Comment: I'll take a look at it and get back to you with a solution.

Comment: A replacement constructor in ProxyHttpTile

Answer (score 0):

This replacement constructor for ProxyHttpTile should eliminate problems associated with cancelling a network tile request.

```
public ProxyHttpTile(Dimension tileSize, BoundingBox bbox, String url) {
    super(tileSize, bbox, null);
    String _url = url;
    String cacheId = url.substring(url.indexOf(":") + 1);
    cacheId = StringUtil.replaceAll(cacheId, "\\", "_");
    cacheId = StringUtil.replaceAll(cacheId, "/", "_");
    cacheId = StringUtil.replaceAll(cacheId, ".", "_");
    cacheId = StringUtil.replaceAll(cacheId, "?", "_");
    cacheId = StringUtil.replaceAll(cacheId, "&", "_");

    ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(url, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            NetworkEvent ne = (NetworkEvent) evt;
            if (ne.getError() == null) {                                                  // Test for exception
                if (ne.getProgressType() == NetworkEvent.PROGRESS_TYPE_COMPLETED) {       // Test for completion
                    Image i = (Image) ne.getMetaData();
                    i.lock();
                    _tile = new Tile(ProxyHttpTile.this.dimension(),
                            ProxyHttpTile.this.getBoundingBox(),
                            i);
                    ProxyHttpTile.this.fireReady();
                }                                                                          // 
            }                                                                              // 
        }
    }, cacheId, true);
}
```

Comment: Can you file that as a pull request so we can integrate it with proper attribution?